# Nvidia 3090 - Cycles Rendering - Crashes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have recently bought a 3090 to use for rendering purposes in blender and I have been encountering ALOT of crashes even when rendering a relative small scene.

I have used both CUDA and Optix options and with and without denoising and adaptive sampling.

The thing that i have noticed is that after rendering a few frames there is a peak on the GPU (see video below) and then blender crashes.
https://youtu.be/72Itc78qK2k

The crash doesnt occur on a specific frame (it may crash after a couple of frames or after 10-15 frames). If I restart blender and continue from the last frame until will crash again.

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly causing these crashes?

- Blender 2.92RC (but also in any other version i have the same issue)
- Cycles
- AMD 3900X
- MSI RTX3090 Supreme
- 32Gb Ram

Comment: Are all your drivers up to date? Also, the video link you posted is unavailable due to being private.

Comment: 30xx cards have been having problems lately. It is possible that there is some bug somewhere. Please read: [best place for bug reports](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: Yes all drivers are up to date. Youtube video updated.

Comment: Same problem here.  3090 works with other apps that are GPU intensive like baking lighting in Unity where it worked exceptionally well.  But rendering in Blender 2.92 almost always results in suddenly closing blender.

Comment: I have the same problem with my 3090 rtx. Is there a solution how to fix this?

Comment: The only "cure" that i have found so far is to render from command line